# Netvibes like "draggable boxes" with javascript

Tags: jquery, windows, draggable, dockable

Do you know any project/framework in javascript (jquery or anything else) that has nice draggable windows that snaps in some fixed places like netvibes has? I found jPolite v2 but it seems a little too complex for what I want to do. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery UI sortable.  Look at the [portlet example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

Comment: Seems great. The only thing that scares me a little is that the windows have all the same width. I'd like the boxes to "resize" to the drop zone if possible, not sure if this plugin will do. But I'll try it if I don't find anything else and post my results. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well I tried it live with firebug and just resizing the column worked, the little boxes resized themselves correctly. So thanks, I'll use that! :)