# Jquery library Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a site that does exactly the same as the BBC website, where you can sort out you elements and reposition them to customise the page, then at the bottom there is a customise page element that lets you restore certain elements, I have done a bit of research and come across the JQuery Droppable library. Will this allow me to close certain elements and then restore these elements at the bottom of the page if need me.

Or should I consider using another library, any comments and help on this post is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the jquery-ui library, you can do much. You can find great examples here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ or http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

(edit : i've seen that bbc website also use the accordion function : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Could you point us the link on what you really want to do ? ("BBC Website" is quite vague)

What do you mean by "close" elements ?
With custom code (and jquery), you can hide easily DOM elements of your page (and reversely, you can show them with one command).

---

**EDIT**

Seems like you are looking for "portal" functions (like Netvibes.com).
You can find :

- a good jquery example here : http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/a-jquery-portal-framework-for-netvibes-like-interfaces-jpolite/
- some great plugins here : http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/08/15-jquery-plugins-for-better-web-page-element-layouts/
- and another example on SO : [Netvibes like "draggable boxes" with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751915/netvibes-like-draggable-boxes-with-javascript)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi max, 

Thank you for your answer, if you got the www.bbc.co.uk below you have different elements for areas of news, e.g sport, radio, weather. These elements can be move re-ordered to suit the viewer. Then at the bottom of the page you have a customise tab that allows you to readd the elements you may of removed when customising your page. 

The other thing then is when you close your browser down and go back to the site, whatever you customised on this page is still there. How is this saved?

Comment: ok. i edit my answer with further elements